# Find the number of strings in the language $(∅∅^∗ + ∅)$

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, strings, kleene-star

Consider the language $L = \emptyset\emptyset^∗ + \emptyset$.

How many words does $L$ contain? Zero or one?

*Note*: $\emptyset^∗ =\{\epsilon\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your language could be simplified as follows, using $\emptyset^* =\{\epsilon\}$:

$$
\begin{align*}
L(\emptyset\emptyset^*+\emptyset)
&=L(  \emptyset . \{\epsilon\} + \emptyset) \\
&=L(\emptyset +\emptyset) &    (\emptyset.\{\epsilon\}=\emptyset) \\
&=L(\emptyset) & (\emptyset + \emptyset = \emptyset)
\end{align*}
$$

So the language L accepts empty language which is $L =\{ \}$, which means that it contains zero elements.

Please be aware that the empty language is different from language consisting of the empty string, which is $L =\{\epsilon\}$, and which contains the element $\epsilon$, while the empty language contains zero elements.